# What are the best algorithms for image segmentation tasks?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request, image-segmentation, u-net

I recently started looking for networks that focus on image segmentation tasks related to biomedical applications. I could not miss the publication [U-Net: Convolutional Networks for Biomedical Image Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) (2015) by Ronneberger, Fischer, and Brox. However, as deep learning is a fast-growing field and the article was published more than 4 years ago, I was wondering if anyone knows other algorithms that yield better results for image segmentation tasks?  And if so, do they also use a U-shape architecture (i.e. contraction path then expansion path with up-conv)?

Comment: You should try doing some research on your own through Google Scholar. According to it the paper that you linked has been referenced 8722 times. Here is a [link](https://scholar.google.hr/scholar?cites=10845403114495995712&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=hr) to all the papers that reference it so try looking through it, you should definitely find something relevant.

Comment: Here's a very related question (if not a duplicate): [What are some good alternatives to U-Net for biomedical image segmentation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/19943/2444).

Answer (score 3):

U-Net and U-Net inspired architectures have been quite popular in the medical image-related tasks ever since it was first introduced. There have been several improved versions of U-Net designed for specific tasks that followed. One such example is [Attention U-Net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03999v3), extremely popular for Pancreas Segmentation.

Other examples of architectures that have achieved state-of-the-art results in image segmentation tasks in recent years include [Multi-Scale 3DCNN + CRF](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05959v3), popular for Brain and Lesion images, [Multi-Scale Attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02849) for MRIs, etc. A recent paper that describes an interesting 3D FCNN architecture is [HyperDense-Net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02967v2), widely used for multi-modal tasks in medical image segmentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can find leaderboards as well as code at [this address](https://paperswithcode.com/task/semantic-segmentation).

For now, [HRNetV2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07919.pdf) leads the game.

The U-Net architecture is part of a broad family of network architectures that aggregate multi-scale features to extract finer details useful for semantic segmentation. Examples are Feature Pyramidal Networks (FPN), Hourglass, Encoder-Decoder, MatrixNet, etc...

[image]